# Universal Relation

Tags: lower-bounds, randomized-algorithms, communication-complexity, streaming-algorithms

In the paper [Tight Bounds for Lp Samplers, Finding Duplicates in Streams, and Related Problems](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1989284.1989289?casa_token=yjE1VqeXAYsAAAAA%3AcAeU-81J7AqJ8GqORSU8-6qi-3jhZKDGHbuOuzvzKBDShzBFhQpKORPmYgCEe4q-ylT4K4irNXGhqi8), the authors consider the **universal relation problem** in 2-party communication complexity, which is defined as follows:

Consider the following two player communication game. Alice gets a string $x \in \{0,1\}^n$, Bob gets $y \in \{0, 1\}^n$ with the promise that $x \ne y$. Alice and Bob exchange messages and the last player must output an index $i \in [n]$ such that $x_i  \ne y_i$.

As part of their proof, the authors use the following lemma, for which they only give a very short proof in the appendix. I have pasted both (literally) below:

**Lemma 7.** Any protocol for UR can be turned into one that outputs every index $i \in [n]$ with $x_i  \ne y_i$ with the same probability. The new protocol uses a joint random source. The number of bits sent, the number of rounds and the error probability does not change.

**Proof of Lemma 7.** Using the joint random source, the players take a uniform random permutation $\pi$ of $[n]$ and use it to permute the digits of $x$ and $y$. Further they take a uniform random subset $S \subseteq [n]$ and flip the digits with coordinates in $S$. This requires no communication. Then they run the original protocol on the modified inputs and report $\pi^{−1}(i)$ if the original protocol reports $i$. All indices where $x$ and $y$ differ are reported with equal probability by symmetry. QED.

I'm having troubles verifying this proof. My understanding is this:

1. Alice and Bob use joint randomness to sample a permutation $\pi$. OK.
2. They both apply $\pi$ to their respective input. OK.
3. Then, it says
   ***"Further they take a uniform random subset $S \subseteq [n]$ and flip the digits with coordinates in $S$."***
   I'm not sure what this means and why this set is needed since they don't seem to be using $S$ in the rest of the proof!
4. Alice and Bob run the original protocol on the modified inputs and report $\pi^{−1}(i)$ if the original protocol reports $i$. They claim that this procedure yields all elements where $x \ne y$ with equal probability "by symmetry".

Could someone explain to me the purpose of Step 3 and provide some hints why this gives each coordinate where $x \ne y$ with same probability?